# use std::vector and memory release

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I am using a `std::vector<CvPoint>` to store edges from a video clip.

```
std::vector<CvPoint> vPt= floodfill(cvPoint(x,y), 255,  0, iplEdgeCpy, 100);
```

When the edge is processed, i am calling swap method to release memory.

```
vector<CvPoint>().swap(myVector);
```

But,  the memory is still not released. It shows that the amount of memory being used by my process is increased.

Anyone can help me or give me some suggestions?

Comment: Your code shouldn't even compile. floodFill is not returning vector. And all its input arguments also do not fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your OS. Under most OSes, the process doesn't give "release" freed memory, it hangs on to it in a free list so that if the process wants to allocate more memory, it already has it and doesn't have to go to the OS.

How are you measuring memory size? If you are worried about leaks, then a tool like valgrind is more useful than just looking at the amount of memory a process has.

Comment: thank you for your replying. I will try to use valgrind to test the memory leaks in my process.